# Behavior of "printf("%d");"

Tags: c, printf

```
int main(){
    // Comment the next line, Garbage value is printed. However, this shows an integer value. 
    int x=32;
    printf("%d");
    return 0;
}
```

Any reason for this behaviour, or is it random??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told `printf()` how to *print* something (*the format specifier `%d`*), but you did not tell `printf()` **what** to print.

To elaborate, you forgot to supply the required argument for the supplied format specifier `%d`.

`C` standard says, if there are insufficient argument for supplied format specifier, the [behaviour is undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, just specifying the format specifier won't magically consider the argument for it. You need to write something like

```
 printf("%d", x);
```

to print the value of `x`.

Answer (score 3):

The `printf()` has the below prototype

```
int printf(const char *,...);
```

What you pass is `%d` to the `printf()` and since this is a format specifier to print out `int` `printf()` looks for the parameter which needs to be printed out since you don't pass any this is undefined behavior

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, stackoverflow doesn't allows me to accept 2 answers !!